# How to set varchar datatype column order by Desc

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have column like below : I have applied orderby percentileno Dec then it gives like below but I need proper order : 1,2,3,--10. 
PercentileNo
1 (0.1-12.6)
10 (113.5-126)
2 (12.7-25.2)
3 (25.3-37.8)
4 (37.9-50.4)
5 (50.5-63)
6 (63.1-75.6)
7 (75.7-88.2)
8 (88.3-100.8)
9 (100.9-113.4)

I need order 
1 (0.1-12.6)
2 (12.7-25.2)
3 (25.3-37.8)
4 (37.9-50.4)
5 (50.5-63)
6 (63.1-75.6)
7 (75.7-88.2)
8 (88.3-100.8)
9 (100.9-113.4)
10 (113.5-126)
Please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me, but if you want to order your list you can do the following:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2
FROM table_1
ORDER BY col_1 DESC
```

So if you have a column called PercentileNo you could do:

```
SELECT PrecentileNo
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY PercentileNo DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for your time I have used order by clause then only it giving PercentileNo 1 (0.1-12.6) 10 (113.5-126) 2 (12.7-25.2) 3 (25.3-37.8) 4 (37.9-50.4) 5 (50.5-63) 6 (63.1-75.6) 7 (75.7-88.2) 8 (88.3-100.8) 9 (100.9-113.4)

Comment: So, your rows are ordered like this:
`ROW 1: x (y-z)
ROW 2: x (y-z)`

Or is it
`ROW 1: x | (y-z)
ROW 2: x | (y-z)`

"|" is a column seperator